# Not able to run unity 3d app properly

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

I have just started to learn `Unity 3D`. I am using [this](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/unity/getting-started-with-unity/) as first lesson. I created a terrain, added texture, plants and grasses, added first person controller and directional lighting. When I press play, the scene automatically starts moving along Y direction. I want the scene to move only when i give input using keyboard or mouse. How to achieve this ?

Comment: The scene usually doesn't move, but your Camera does! And what I can see from your own answer, you've attached a script to the Camera which follows your First Person Controller. Just something I wanted to explain...

Comment: @Joetjah to add to your answer, it seems that the camera keeps moving along `Y` axis till it meets a terrain.

Comment: No, that is incorrect, unless you attached a `Rigidbody` to your camera. I will explain my comment: The reason the camera falls down, is because you scripted it to follow your `Player`. And if your `Player` falls down, the Camera follows. So the camera does exactly what you wanted it to do, only your `Player` was wrong.

Comment: I am confused now. When I play the game the camera keep moving infinetly without any input from me. Only after I placed the camera above the terrain, it stopped moving when it levelled with the terrain. Couls you please explain this ?

Comment: Did you attach the `FirstPersonController`-Component to the `Camera` object? A normal hierarchy would be that you inserted a `GameObject` (perhaps a cilinder), which has a child: `Main Camera`. You attach the FirstPersonController component to that cilinder (that is what you control). Then, you can attach a Camera to the script. It'll automatically move and rotate the camera depending on your FirstPersonController's location. If that's under the terrain, it'll fall down, and the camera stays on that position (thus falling down with the FirstPersonController)

Comment: So again, if you attached the FirsPersonController component to the Camera, the Camera is the player. That's usually a wrong way to develop a game, unless you want something like a spectator mode.

Comment: http://unity3d.com/gallery/demos/live-demos Check these links for some nice tutorials and examples.

Comment: `FirstPersonController` has inbuilt camera to which it is attached, I deleted the main camera.

Comment: So, is the "falling of `FirstPersonController` " a gravity kind of implementation.

Comment: Unity provedes a large easyness in coding the basic map layouts and handling character movement and gravity-like situations. Yes, you most likely have a Rigidbody attached to your FirstpersonController. Rigidbodies enable your GameObjects to act under the control of physics. The Rigidbody can receive forces and torque to make your objects move in a realistic way. Any GameObject must contain a Rigidbody to be influenced by gravity, act under added forces via scripting, or interact with other objects through the NVIDIA PhysX physics engine. So in short yes, your FirstPersonController fell down!

Comment: Check out http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Rigidbody.html for more information on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first person controller has to be placed above the terrain completely. After doing this I get the desired effect.

Comment: This statement is correct. Do note that the Camera and the FirstPersonController are not necessarely the same thing.